# Organizer name appears in calendar view subject for appointment

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, calendar

I noticed this appeared recently in our Exchange 2010 upgrade: in certain appointments, the organizer's name will appear with the subject in the appointment.  In this case, there is only one person in the appointment (the organizer) and no resources have been allocated.  Can the organizer's name be removed from the calendar view?

Comment: For the appointment in question - was it created on a shared calendar, like a room or resource calendar?

Comment: No, an individual's calendar

Comment: And just to be clear, the item is on an individual's calendar and the DID NOT also include a conference room or resource calendar in the appointment?

Comment: No resources - no rooms

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the user's calendar AutomateProcessing flag is set to AutoAccept, which then checks the AddOrganizerToSubject setting and, if set to true, adds the organizer to the subject as you are experiencing.

The default setting for AutomateProcessing on a user mailbox is AutoUpdate.  To check what this setting currently is for the user, run this command in the Exchange Management Shell:

```
Get-CalendarProcessing [primary_email_address] | Select AutomateProcessing
```

To set the mailbox back to AutoUpdate for the AutomateProcessing setting, run this command:

```
Set-CalendarProcessing [primary_email_address] -AutomateProcessing AutoUpdate
```

More information about the `Set-CalendarProcessing` command is available at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335046.aspx

Comment: This might be helpful.  More info: I only see the name in the OWA calendar, but not in the Outlook calendar.  Are there different calendar processing switches for OWA?

Comment: I'm not aware of differences between OWA and Outlook for calendar processing switches. The interesting thing is AutoAccept should only work for resource mailboxes, not user mailboxes. Run the command "Get-Mailbox [primary_email_address] | Select RecipientTypeDetails" and let me know what type of mailbox this is showing up as.  Also let me know what the "Get-CalendarProcessing" command above returned.  I've tried several variations of settings and haven't yet been able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Yes, it is a user mailbox, not a resource (get-mailbox)
Autoupdate is on for get-calendarprocessing, with addorganizertosubject set to false

Comment: Are there any delegates or any other shared permissions on the mailbox in question?  You say that the organizer name only appears in the subject when viewing in OWA, not Outlook?  Does the owner of the mailbox see the same thing - if they look in OWA is the name there and in Outlook it is not?  This appointment was just a normal appointment or was it a meeting request (i.e. sent to other people)?  You've definitely stumbled upon an interesting one here.

Comment: Correction: it does appear in Outlook (my bad)

Comment: Is this appearing for every item that the person schedules on their calendar?

Comment: For me it is; still, 6 years later..

Answer (score 0):

Set-CalendarProcessing *mailbox* -AddOrganizerToSubject $false -deletesubject $false

That will stop Exchange from adding the organizer to the subject, and also stop it from deleting the original subject.